# Audio play from SQlite Blob in Swift

Tags: ios, audio, sqlite, blob, swift2

I am using sqlite3 with fmdb and xcode6.1 (swift).
I store my audio file to a sqlite database (as BLOB) and now I want to gain it from db and also play it when a button clicked.

When I extracted the audio files from db,it is outputed as "ID3".
What data type is need to gain the data comes from blob type from db and how to play that blob data.
I am new to the iOS developing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get the BLOB data out of the database as `NSData` using FMDB, you use [`dataForColumn`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMResultSet.html#//api/name/dataForColumn:) or [`dataForColumnIndex`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMResultSet.html#//api/name/dataForColumnIndex:).

Comment: yap,i got it. but i don't know how to play audio by that.When i searched , I only found play audio mp3 in project (by adding mp3 file in project).

Comment: ID3 is not a music file format. It's a container for meta data, often associated with (or part of) a MP3 file. Are you sure you're not dealing with MP3 file?

Comment: yap , now i got it. Get the data as NSData and  play that audio . Thanks.    var AudioData : NSData!  var Audio : AVAudioPlayer?   audio = AVAudioPlayer(data:AudioData , error:nil)  audio?.prepareToPlay()  audio?.play()